Error launching the IntelliJ IDEA 2023.34: "Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main"
I wanted to live update Java classes in Intellij IDEA.
So, when I explored for a solution, I came across this documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

I followed all these steps and selected the new runtime to JDK 11 only to find out that my IDE configuration has been messed up:

Now whenever I start the application, it pops up with an error message saying:
Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main

I don't want to reinstall the IDE. How can this issue be fixed?

Changing default JetBrains runtime (JBR) to a custom one is not recommended in most cases unless it was suggested by JetBrains team. A custom runtime may not contain necessary features and fixes needed for a proper launch of IntelliJ IDEA
Please switch to the default runtime as described here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under (see: Switch back to the default bundled JetBrains Runtime) to make the IDE working again
See also the official documentation page Reload Modified Classes on how to Hotswap Java code

I observed the JAVA_HOME was updated to JDK_8u25. I updated it to JDK11, but it did not fix the problem though.
I finally planned to clear all the settings and reinstall the IDE, and I am able to start it properly.
